# Android - prompt users for device pin when performing push notification actions on lock screen

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

My notifications have action buttons. When a notification arrives on the lock screen and the user taps the action button, I need the device pin screen to show up, and after entering the pin, the action (in my case the action is an API call to the server) should be performed without bringing up a notification activity. Right now, on lock screen, action gets performed directly without prompting user for the device pin. I'd like to fix that.

When the notification arrives when the device is unlocked, users should be able to tap the action buttons directly without seeing a notification activity.

My research on stackoverflow landed me on many questions on the reverse - many people ask about how to perform actions on lock screens without the device pin. In my case however I never get the device pin prompt. What setting in code brings up the device pin when users perform notification actions on lock screen?

My code below would cause the notification actions to be performed on lock screen without prompting for pin:

```
private void displayChallengeNotification(Context context, ChallengeInformation extras) {
    /* build the notification */
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_SECRET)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.status_bar_icon)
                    .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.push_notification_title))
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(getChallengeContextString(extras)))
                    .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.push_notification_description))
                    .setAutoCancel(false) 
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.notification))
                    .setLocalOnly(true) 
                    .setDefaults(DEFAULTS);

    /* set the target of the notification */
    PendingIntent challenge =
            getChallengePendingIntent(context, extras);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(challenge);

    addNotificationActions(mBuilder, context, extras);

    challengeTracker.notifyChallenge(extras, context, mBuilder.build());
}

private PendingIntent getChallengePendingIntent(Context context, ChallengeInformation extras) {

    Intent challenge = getChallengeIntent(context, extras);

    /* set up the back stack so that navigation works as expected */
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(challenge);

    int notificationId = extras.getTransactionId().hashCode();
    PendingIntent challengePendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(notificationId, 0);
    return challengePendingIntent;
}

private static Intent getChallengeIntent(Context context, ChallengeInformation info) {
    /* set up the intent to launch the challenge screen */
    Intent challenge = new Intent(context, PushChallengeActivity.class);
    challenge.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    /* get the information for the challenge */
    challenge.putExtras(info.getBundle());
    if (info.isChallengeAccepted() != null) {
        challenge.putExtra(Constants.IS_CHALLENGE_ACCEPTED, info.isChallengeAccepted());
    }

    return challenge;
}
```

Comment: What happens now when you press an action button in a notification when the screen is locked?

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman the action directly gets performed without prompting for device pin. In my case, the server gets the user response, the notification disappears from the device, and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

> My code below would cause the notification actions to be performed on lock screen without prompting for pin

Its behaving as expected. Notification actions are executed immediately once they are clicked by the user.

At present there is no direct way to defer this action until user has unlocked the phone.

The best workaround would be to start the notification activity and `onResume()` of your activity, perform necessary action.

You can also have a look on Notification [lock screen visibility options](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#lockscreenNotification) to avoid showing your notification on lock screen. But, do take note on following:

> However, the user always has final control over whether their notifications are visible on the lock screen and can even control that based on your app's notification channels.

Comment: If I start the notification activity, then even when the device is unlocked, the action can no longer be performed directly, which worsens the user experience. Any way to have the app asks for pin on lock screen, but directly perform actions when unlocked without bringing up the activity?

Comment: `If I start the notification activity, then even when the device is unlocked, the action can no longer be performed directly` Your Notification activity will be immediately brought in foregroud and `onResume()` will be called. You can do the action automatically. You can more over just start a transparent activity (change the background color to transparent) and close it once action is completed.